# ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1 with same number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I try to create new columns in my DataFrame 'self.__transformed' by copying some columns of 'self.__original'

```
self.__transformed[new_col] = self.__original[col]
```

However I get this error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

`new_col` and `col` are lists of column names

This : `print(len(col), len(new_col))` returns: 45 45

By doing `display(self.__original[col])` I see my 45 columns without anything special.

I don't understand what can be the possible reason of this error as I have the same numbers of columns. In particular I don't understand why `passed 2` because I have 45 columns, not 2 !?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Wrong number of items passed - Meaning and suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196907/valueerror-wrong-number-of-items-passed-meaning-and-suggestions)

Comment: I learned there that a possible reason for this error is that I don't have any rows in my DataFrames but I have 4321 rows in both. Obviously self.__transformed[new_col] is empty because I'm creating these columns, is it a problem ?

Comment: I solved my problem using `c = [i for i in self.__transformed.columns if not(i in col)]
            self.__transformed = self.pd.concat([self.__transformed[c], self.__original[col]], axis=1)`