# Value error when copying a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to copy values from one column to another using the following:

```
df1999['H31C'] = df1999['H31B']
```

However I am getting this value error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is the contents of 'df1999'?

Comment: @Morteza it's quite a large pandas dataframe

Comment: The error is basically saying you're trying to copy 2 columns into 1 column. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216241/7924381.

Comment: `df1999['H31B']` is probably a dataframe with 2 columns instead of just being 1 column. you likely have duplicate column names