# 'method' object is not subscriptable - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, methods, jupyter-notebook

I have the following two lines of codes

```
temp['AD_Free_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']=='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin['SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD']) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]

temp['AD_Paid_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']!='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin['SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD']) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]
```

Can someone please help me understand the error and how can I fix it? Thank You

Comment: missing `(` in `.isin([`

Comment: typo, so closing

Answer (score 2):

That is because [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) is a function for Series but you are using it like .isin[] ...,
You can replace it as `isin(...)`, as follows:

```py
temp['AD_Free_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']=='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin('SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD')) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]

temp['AD_Paid_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']!='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin('SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD')) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]
```

If you use like isin[...], Python will think it is a kind of subscriptable variable such as a list (e.g., a[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), a[2] ...)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo

Comment: I changed my code around isin function temp['AD_Free_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']=='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin(['SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD'])) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]

    temp['AD_Paid_Cancel'] = temp[(temp['ISFREEPOLICY']!='N') & (temp['PRODUCT'].isin(['SAD1','SAD2','SAD3','SAD4','SADFR1','SADFR2','SIAD'])) & (temp['POLICYSTATUS']=='C')]
but now getting error "Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1" Please help

Comment: @MithileshTiwari It is really hard to guess why it happens without any backgound knowledge. As I guess, `temp['AD_Free_Cancel']` is a Series but it seems that you are trying to assign `Dataframe` with 12 columns into a `Series`, which has 1 column. That is logically wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216241/1779532

Answer (score 0):

You are having error because isin() is a function but you are using it as .isin[], It should be isin()